# Why are reputation points lost for deleted questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-questions

This is the question I am referring to: *[Is jQuery dead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424456/is-jquery-dead)*

Reputation points can be lost for downvotes. But if any question is deleted, shouldn't the the user get back his/her reputation points?

Comment: Don't they? I see that they got back the 10 net reputation that they lost from the 2 upvotes and 10 (!) downvotes on their question.

Comment: Well, is it dead?  Can someone please make absolutely sure?

Comment: Well, got it. Actually I searched on meta but did not get the above question in my search result. May be I searched with different keyword. However, I think this duplicate question with 10 negative vote should be deleted.

Comment: [You don't gain or lose reputation on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Reputation gained from a question or an answer to a question is lost when it is deleted, yes.

When you delete a question, you will also get the reputation back that you lost on downvote, but not immediately, instead you get it when the next recalc is triggered.

Usually that happens within an hour.

Note that reputation lost from Upvotes for deleted questions is preserved when the answer you gave is at least 60 days old and has a score of 3 or higher.

[What else should I know about deleted posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222)

Comment: There are definitely a lot more caveats to this. I recently tried deleting a post that had 4 downvotes (thinking about this post, I assumed I'd get my points back), but instead, I lost 4 additional points and my account was put on temporary suspension.

Comment: I just deleted a post I created that only had 5 views, no votes up or down nor comments nor answers. I lost 2 points.

Comment: @GTAE86 what did you do to earn the two points you lost? points aren't deducted randomly. Either you received a downvote somewhere unrelated to your deleted post or you earned 2 rep on that post.

Comment: Not sure - I had been at 1770 for some months. Deleted the post, and was then at 1768. I see I am back at 1770 now, so ended up a no-op.