# Post removed reputation increase

Tags: bug, reputation, automatic-deletion

I am bit confused about what happened here. I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729478/how-do-i-change-this-function-to-a-recursive-function) that had -4. causing a -8 reputation decrease. Today I got a +8 on my reputation and the reason given is removed. Do auto removed questions restore your reputation? Why would that happen?

Just to clarify, I've read in the past that deleting your question does not remove negative reputation, and you are encouraged to attempt and fix the quality of your question. I attempted to fix the quality by adding a fiddle that had expected inputs and outputs. However, the question was auto deleted which is fine, but I am just wondering why deleting your own question does not restore reputation loss, but auto deletion does restore reputation loss?

Comment: See [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320463/957731) and the page it links to for more details, but basically this is as designed.

Comment: What would be a reason for the reputation loss to remain? It would be a punishment, one you don't deserve.

Comment: well just I've read in the past deleting your own question does not remove the negative reputation. so I'm wondering why it is different on auto deletion

Comment: Unless the post is at least 60 days old and had a score of 3 or higher, you lose all reputation gain / regain all lost reputation from that post. You may confuse it with post bans and the positive question record - in these cases, even deleted posts still count (but they don't affect your reputation).

Comment: @jeanne dark  oh ok,  thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Deleted posts can still count towards a question ban. Perhaps that is what you are thinking of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, reputations changes do result from deleted questions (and answers). This is not a bug, just the way the site is designed to work... You only get reputation from contributions that are actually on the site.

Comment: IIRC, answers that've been around for more than 60 days and has more than 3 votes do not affect reputation when they're delted. Not sure about questions, but I'm guessing it's the same

Comment: @Zoe [correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141682/394554)